# Subtract transpose from a matrix but keep the original diagonal

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following matrix in numpy

```
mat = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 100, (3, 3))
        A   B   C
     A [69, 88, 64],
     B [92, 17, 35],
     C [ 8, 74, 39]
```

Is there a pythonic way (i.e. avoid nested loops) to subtract mat(A,B) from mat(B,A); mat(A,C) from mat(C,A) and so on....? The diagonal elements can be left alone. The result should be:

```
        A       B     C
     A [69,   88-92, 64-8],
     B [92-88, 17,   35-74],
     C [8-64,  74-35, 39]
```

which becomes:

```
       A   B   C
     A [69, -4, 56],
     B [4, 17, -39],
     C [-56, 39, 39]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the off-diagonal terms easily enough:

```
>>> mat = np.array([[69, 88, 64], [92, 17, 35], [8, 74, 39]])
>>> mat
array([[69, 88, 64],
       [92, 17, 35],
       [ 8, 74, 39]])
>>> mat - mat.T
array([[  0,  -4,  56],
       [  4,   0, -39],
       [-56,  39,   0]])
```

To put the diagonal back, you could do

```
>>> m = (mat - mat.T) + np.diag(np.diag(mat))
>>> m
array([[ 69,  -4,  56],
       [  4,  17, -39],
       [-56,  39,  39]])
```

or maybe:

```
>>> m = (mat - mat.T)
>>> np.fill_diagonal(m, mat.diagonal())
>>> m
array([[ 69,  -4,  56],
       [  4,  17, -39],
       [-56,  39,  39]])
```

Comment: Beat me by about a minute

Answer (score 1):

```
mata = mat
matb = mat - matrix.transpose(mat)
for i in range(len(mat)):
     matb[i][i] = mata[i][i]
```

Are these loops too nested?